# Excluding x509 authentication from specific URLs

Tags: java, spring, x509certificate, boot

I'm developing a Spring Boot project in which someone could sign in using it's certificate. Most of the tutorials and posts I've read and followed talk about client-authentication in the whole site while I only want authentication to happen when accessing secured resources (whose URLs are `secure/**`). There are some posts similar to my topic but haven't guided me in the right direction yet.

I have already setted up SSL on the server and works fine. Client auth also works as expected but on every page.

Is it possible to run client-auth on just some pages but not on others? I want the user to be autheticated using it's certificate on certain pages while others doesn't need any kind of client authentication.

This is the application.properties for my project:

```
server.ssl.enabled=true

server.ssl.key-store=classpath:****
server.ssl.key-store-password=****
server.ssl.key-password=****
server.ssl.key-alias=localhost


server.ssl.trust-store=****
server.ssl.trust-store-password=****

server.ssl.client-auth=want

server.port=8443
```

Also, this is the config I used for authentication:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig {
        
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain certificateFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/user/**")
                    .permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/seguro/**")
                    .authenticated()
                .and()
                .x509()
                    .subjectPrincipalRegex("CN=(.*?)(?:,|$)")
                    .userDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new UserDetailsService() {
            @Override
            public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
                System.out.println("USERNAME -> " + username);
                if (username.contains("Bob")) {
                    return new User(username, "", AuthorityUtils.commaSeparatedStringToAuthorityList("ROLE_USER"));
                }
                throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found!");
            }
        };
    }

}
```